# How to read sentence instead of line with WordCount MapReduce tutorial

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am learning Hadoop MapReduce and I am following the WordCount [tutorial](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html).

In the following piece of code, I understand that the `map` method, processes one line at a time, as provided by the specified `TextInputFormat`. It then splits the line into tokens separated by whitespaces, via the `StringTokenizer`, and emits a key-value pair of `[<word>, 1]`:

```
public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
    while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(itr.nextToken());
        context.write(word, one);
    }
}
```

How can I edit this code in order to read a sentence instead of a line per time?

E.g. of input text:
`This is my first sentence. This is the second sentence.`

I want to read first `This is my first sentence.` and then `This is the second sentence.` instead of `This`, `is`, `my`, `first`, ...

and have as output:

```
1 This is my first sentence.
1 This is the second sentence.
```

because the sentence `This is my first sentence.` appears only one time in the input text and also the sentence `This is the second sentence.` appear one time in the text.

Suppose that the input text is like this:

`This is my first sentence. This is my first sentence. This is the second sentence.`

then the output would be like this:

```
2 This is my first sentence.
1 This is the second sentence.
```

because the sentence `This is my first sentence.` appears two times in the input text and the sentence `This is the second sentence.` appears only one time in the text.

Fyi, the output of the WordCount is:

```
2 This
2 is
1 my
1 first
2 sentence
1 second
```

because the term `This` appears two time in the input text, the term `is` appeats two times in the text, the term `my` appears one time in the text etc..

**SOLUTION: conf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", ". "):**

As delimiter I set `". "` (with the space). Now my code recognises the sentences but the output file is wrong. With the following input file:

`This is my first sentence. This is my first sentence. This is the second sentence.`

The output file that it generates is like this (some white spaces and then the number 3):

```
            3
```

Instead of like this:

```
 2 This is my first sentence
 1 This is the second sentence
```

Here is my code:

```
 public class SentenceCount {

      public static class SentenceMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

           private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
           private Text word = new Text();

           public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
           //System.out.println("SENTENCE: " + value.toString());
           context.write(word, one);
     }
 }


 public static class IntSumReducer extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
      private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

     public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
          int sum = 0;
          for (IntWritable val : values) {
               sum += val.get();
       }
       result.set(sum);
       context.write(key, result);
     }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      Configuration conf = new Configuration();
      conf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", ". ");
      Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "sentence count");
      job.setJarByClass(SentenceCount.class);
      job.setMapperClass(SentenceMapper.class);
      job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
      job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
      job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
      job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
      FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
      FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
      System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
 }
 }
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to count sentences instead of words? Can you provide an example input and the output you'd expect from the 2 different approaches?

Comment: yes I would like to count sentences. Btw, I added three examples to better explain my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward solution would be to pre-process your input and put each sentence in a new line, and keep using the `TextInputFormat` as is.

Another way to approach this, you can override `TextInputFormat`'s default delimiter (newline character: `\n`)

You can change the delimiter to `.` like so:

`conf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", ".")` - in the Driver class.

(Be cautious though, you'll get wrong results if the "." character appears inside a sentence (e.g. `"This pen costs 1.55 dollars."`) or if a sentence ends with an exclamation mark instead of a full-stop.)

Then in your `map()` method you no longer need to tokenize the sentence.

```
public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
   context.write(value, one);
}
```

Comment: I have tried to implement your solution (please check **SOLUTION: conf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", ". ")** . As you can see, it recognizes the sentences but the output file is wrong. Where am I wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Replace `context.write(word, one);` with `context.write(value, one);` in your `map()`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of tokenizing on 'white spaces', you would need to tokenize based on sentence delimiter (period '.' in this case. So, use of RegEx might help.

Also, keep in mind some of the corner cases. For example: how would you like to treat the following? As two sentences or three?

"This is my first sentence. This is my second sentence.". Now I have a third sentence.

Does the double quoted portion to be treated as one sentence or two (based on "" or .)?